# Symfony - Sonata Admin - Redirect from FormField to List

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

is there a way to redirect from a createAction to listAction in SonataAdminBundle?

I'm needing it to redirect user when access denied.

```
$curUser = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
    if ($this->getSubject()->getId() && $this->getSubject()->getUser()) {
        if ($this->getSubject()->getUser() != $curUser) {
            REDIRECT HERE
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to add use RedirectResponse class.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
```

After that :

```
$curUser = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
if ($this->getSubject()->getId() && $this->getSubject()->getUser()) {
    if ($this->getSubject()->getUser() != $curUser) {
        $redirection = new RedirectResponse($this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('router')->generate('your_route_name'));
        $redirection->send();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Fatih Kahveci, thank you - is there a way to get the sonata list route from this form?

Comment: @cRsakaWolf I am not sure but you can't find list route name in form. But you can easily find using debug:router command and find whatever route name you want.